# Apply CSS to Menu Issue in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I need to apply CSS to a menu list with selected one only in Meteor JS? I have done this but it selects the color to all menu list. Can anybody tell me why my code doesn't work?

Html Code :

```
<div class="mhome">
      {{#each menuitems}}
         <div class="menu">
               <div class="menulist {{isselected}}">{{this}}</div>
          </div>
      {{/each}}
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
var selectItemName;
var ItemList = [
                 'A','B', 'C', 'D', 
                 'E','F', 'G',
                 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'
               ]

Template.mhome.menuitems = function ()
 {
   return ItemList;
 };

Template.mhome.events
 ({
    'click .menulist': function (e,t)
     {
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
      console.log("You pressed the MENU ITEMS Button");
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("this.name="+e.target.innerHTML);
      selectItemName = e.target.innerHTML;
      Session.set("selectedItem", selectItemName);
      if(e.target.innerHTML == "F")
         {
          console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>F");
          Session.set('ContentItemTemplate', 'f');
         }

     }
 });
//For CSS
Template.mhome.isselected = function ()
{
 return Session.equals("selectedItem", selectItemName) ? "selected" : '';
};
```

CSS :

```
.menulist.selected
 {
  color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `isselected` template helper.

`Session.equals("selectedItem", selectItemName)` always evaluates to `true` since you set it to the same value in your click event handler.

Try this instead:

```
Template.mhome.isselected = function ()
{
    return Session.equals("selectedItem", this.toString()) ? "selected" : '';
};
```